# React e React Native se comunicam facilmente?

Tags: react, react-native

Eu preciso fazer uma aplicação web, porém a mesma precisa ser executada nas plataformas **Android** como **IOS**. Apesar de saber a diferença entre os Frameworks, gostaria de saber  se eu consigo fazer um código utilizando o **React** normal, mas juntamente criar as conexões com arquivos XML do **React Native**.

Não sei se consegui ser claro, e desculpa pela ignorância, mais estou iniciando na área.

Comment: Talvez [isso](https://medium.com/@gwen_faraday/converting-a-react-app-to-react-native-d7df17968fc6) ajude

Comment: Isso vai ajudar muito Caio, grato pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia Arenas,

Não diria que se comunicam, mas possuem uma estrutura semelhante, visto que React Native é um framework baseado no React. Ou seja teremos algumas semelhanças como o design, pois você usará JSX e JavaScript.

Em um resumo grosseiro você pode reaproveitar algumas estruturas(o que vai mudar  na maioria das vezes são as tags)

**ReacJS:** é uma biblioteca (Desenvolvimento para web)+-

**React Native:** é um framework (Desenvolvimento mobile)

Lembre-se no react native você não está escrevendo para a web, então você não pode usar os elementos regulares de HTML, como `div`, `input`, `span`, e por ai vai. Ao invés desses elementos, você tem um vários componentes nativos que React Native fornece [aqui](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator.html).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Isso esclareceu muito minha duvida, fico grato pela atenção e a explicação!